# How to make Jsoup fetch the desktop version of a URL

Tags: android, html, web, jsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape web-pages for their meta-data using JSoup in an Android app, but it's ending up downloading mobile versions for websites. Is there a way to make websites believe that the request is coming from a desktop client?

Answer (score 1):

Use desktop user-agent, something like that:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
      .referrer("http://www.google.com")
      .get();
```